# Replace all occurrences of ' 1 ' with matched text in one line

Tags: regular-expression, match

I've got a text file, containing following lines

```
<a href="tg://proxy?server=radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs&port=443&secret=ee32b920dffb51643028e2f6b878d4eac175706c6f6164626f792e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">1<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne&port=443&secret=ee000000000000000000000000000000006b65746161626f6e6c696e652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#IE">2<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=103.105.48.76&port=443&secret=eefacacf88a07e73d961d7029c1da7e64b64756f6c696e676f2e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#GB">3<p> </a>
...
<a href="tg://proxy?server=5.28.193.20&port=443&secret=eed41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8322e7777772e676f6f676c652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#DE">1315<p> </a>
```

I want to replace all `...>1<p>`, `...>2<p>`, ... near line ends with server addresses.

The text above should become

```
<a href="tg://proxy?server=radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs&port=443&secret=ee32b920dffb51643028e2f6b878d4eac175706c6f6164626f792e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne&port=443&secret=ee000000000000000000000000000000006b65746161626f6e6c696e652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#IE">digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=103.105.48.76&port=443&secret=eefacacf88a07e73d961d7029c1da7e64b64756f6c696e676f2e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#GB">103.105.48.76<p> </a>
...
<a href="tg://proxy?server=5.28.193.20&port=443&secret=eed41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8322e7777772e676f6f676c652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#DE">5.28.193.20<p> </a>
```

Please, scroll right to see the difference.

In other words, being opened in a browser, this file is rendered as a list of numbers, each of which is a link to the Telegram proxy. I want to replace these numbers with server addresses to make it look more pleasant.

I guess, `g` command can do the job, however, I don't know how to access matched group or matched pattern.

I've tried many variants, and the best is

`:g/server=\(.*\)&/y a|s#>\[0-9\]\+<#\=getreg('a')#`

It does not work, because `y a` command yanks the whole line while I need only part of it. And numbers in subsequent `s` command are not matched.

Is there any way to do it from the `:` line, without writing additional functions?

I understand that this task can be easily done with awk + sed, however, I think this is not sportive :)

Comment: Sounds like a sed, grep awk piping problem. Maybe you should ask here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's not sportive :)

Comment: maybe `:%!sed ...`       :)

Comment: Unrelated, but why is there a `<p>` tag without closing `</p>` within the `<a></a>`? This does not look like clean HTML.

Comment: @Friedrich, the goal is to quickly find working proxy. I open this file in a browser, then each time I click on lines, browser opens Telegram, and I can check if it works.

Comment: Asking for external help is not sportive.

Comment: @wl2776 you could achieve the same with well-formed HTML. Well, whatever floats your raft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about `:help :global`.

The point of `:g/<pattern>/<command>` is to execute `<command>` on **the lines that match `<pattern>`**, not on the matches themselves.

This means that, in this case, `:global` is largely unnecessary if you want to use a substitution.

Let's simplify your sample a bit:

```
<a href="tg://proxy?server=r.r.e.r.r.sbs&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">1<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=d-c-h-c.1.melbourne&p=443&s=c0ffe&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#IE">2<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=103.105.48.76&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#GB">3<p> </a>
```

What you want to do can be done with a single substitution:

```
:%s/\(^.*server=\)\(.\{-}\)\(&.\{-}>\)\d\{-}/\1\2\3\2
```

The idea is to slice the line into capture groups during the search phase, and reconstruct the line how we want it in the replace phase.

First the slicing:

```
<a href="tg://proxy?server=r.r.e.r.r.sbs&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">1<p> </a>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA
                           BBBBBBBBBBBBB
                                                                             C
```

where `A` is the part we want to keep as-is, `B` is the part we want to reuse elsewhere, and `C` is the part we want to replace with `B`. What comes after `C` is irrelevant so we can concentrate on what comes before:

```
"pattern
\(^.*server=\)\(.\{-}\)\(&.\{-}>\)
+------------+                     group #1
              +-------+            group #2
                       +---------+ group #3

" sample
<a href="tg://proxy?server=r.r.e.r.r.sbs&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">1<p> </a>
+-------------------------+                                                   group #1
                           +-----------+                                      group #2
                                        +-----------------------------------+ group #3
```

Now that we have everything that comes before `C` split in three capture groups, we can reconstruct that part easily:

```
" replacement
\1\2\3

" result
<a href="tg://proxy?server=r.r.e.r.r.sbs&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES"><p> </a>
```

and follow up with group #2, which contains the server name:

```
" replacement
\1\2\3\2

" result
<a href="tg://proxy?server=r.r.e.r.r.sbs&p=443&s=c0ffee&b=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">r.r.e.r.r.sbs<p> </a>
```

There is nothing hard to remember, here:

- `\(...\)` creates a capture group,
- `\2` uses capture group #2.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation. What is `{-}`? Never seen this before

Comment: It's a quantifier, meaning "zero or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible". See `:help \{-`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
%s/proxy?server=\zs\([^&]*\)\(&.*\)\d\ze<p>/\1\2\1/
```

Here is an explanation:

- `proxy?server=\zs` catch the url but ignore the first part for the replacement (`\zs`)
- `\([^&]*\)`catch the server name and store it into `\1`
- `\(&.*\)\d\ze<p>` catch the rest into `\2` but exclude `<p>` from the replacement
- `\1\2\1` do the replacement you want.

Answer (score 1):

If sed can do, it `:substitute` can do it as well (well, mostly).

Using this command: `:s/server=\([^&]*\).*>\zs\d\+\ze<p>/\1/`

Will convert each of these lines:

```html
<a href="tg://proxy?server=radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs&port=443&secret=ee32b920dffb51643028e2f6b878d4eac175706c6f6164626f792e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">1<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne&port=443&secret=ee000000000000000000000000000000006b65746161626f6e6c696e652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#IE">2<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=103.105.48.76&port=443&secret=eefacacf88a07e73d961d7029c1da7e64b64756f6c696e676f2e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#GB">3<p> </a>
...
<a href="tg://proxy?server=5.28.193.20&port=443&secret=eed41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8322e7777772e676f6f676c652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#DE">1315<p> </a>
```

into these:

```html
<a href="tg://proxy?server=radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs&port=443&secret=ee32b920dffb51643028e2f6b878d4eac175706c6f6164626f792e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#ES">radan.rooznameh.etellaate.rooz.romatism.sbs<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne&port=443&secret=ee000000000000000000000000000000006b65746161626f6e6c696e652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#IE">digkala-com-heneri-com.1400.melbourne<p> </a>
<a href="tg://proxy?server=103.105.48.76&port=443&secret=eefacacf88a07e73d961d7029c1da7e64b64756f6c696e676f2e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#GB">103.105.48.76<p> </a>
...
<a href="tg://proxy?server=5.28.193.20&port=443&secret=eed41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8322e7777772e676f6f676c652e636f6d&bot=@mtpro_xyz_bot#DE">5.28.193.20<p> </a>
```

Note that this runs on a single line only; use `:%s...` to run on the whole buffer.